# htaccess exclude file from rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to exclude a single file from a rewrite rule that otherwise forces all requests to https.  The rule itself works, but I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for the exception.

I am trying to exclude GET requests that look like:

`http://savepostage.com/cgi-bin/version.pl`
or the same with `?[somestring]` appended

Here's what I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!.\version.pl
RewriteRule ^(.)$ https://savepostage.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It forces all requests to https, regardless of whether I include or delete the second line.

I must be missing some syntax here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/version\.pl$`

Comment: Duh!  Amazing how long I can look at something and not see the obvious. Thanks so much for the quick response, and for not pointing out how obvious the answer was.

Comment: the dude @anubhava is smart man that's why he has 370k repo and 32 gold ,there should be a Olympic for coders too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this '/' for a sub-directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/version\.pl$
```

The rule will be skipped if file is `version.pl` where '^' matches the exact 'version' file name